# Interpreting interactions in 2 way ANOVA

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, interpretation

I ran a 2 way anova with 2 categorical IVs, i.e. age(young/old) and condition(control/low alcohol/high alcohol/marijuana) and 1 continuous IV. Most critically, here are my p-values on my interaction variables:

```
conditionLow_alcohol:ageYoung      0.32096    
conditionHigh_alcohol:ageYoung     0.11353    
conditionMarijuana:ageYoung        0.01446 < 0.05
```

as you can see only the `marijuana:young` interaction was significant.

My question is, how do I interpret this result? Do I say that there is an interaction between age and condition only when participants are in the marijuana group? or can I say more generally that there is an interaction between condition and age?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you used R's `lm()` function to perform this analysis. R has a very funky way of doing factorial ANOVA, and unless you made some critical adjustments, it will not give you the results you might expect from SAS or SPSS. First, R uses Type I SS, which means the effects depend on the order you enter your independent variables. Second, R uses a contrast coding scheme that is appropriate for regression but not for ANOVA. In particular, by default it uses treatment coding, which means that you aren't able to get a valid overall F-test for the effect of an interaction. So you can't simply say that the interaction is statistically significant. Your results imply that the effect of being young and taking marijuana increases relative to the expected combination of the main effects for each. That's not really a complete statement about the interaction as a whole, and the F-test for that interaction may not be significant (which is weird, I agree). [This free book](http://health.adelaide.edu.au/psychology/ccs/docs/lsr/lsr-0.5.pdf#page=513) is an excellent guide to this issue.

Comment: That link doesn't work anymore